zählen vs auszählen
What is the difference between "auszählen" and "zählen" when they mean to count something? The DWDS dictionary defines "auszählen" as "durch Zählen die genaue Anzahl ermitteln" (meaning 1) and "zählen" as "die Anzahl von etw. feststellen" (meaning 2). Both seem identical to me.
Related example with the "Auszählung" noun:

Nach Auszählung fast aller Stimmen hat die konservative Partei
deutlich weniger Sitze erhalten als die Demokraten.

(source: https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/tagesschau/ts-64174.html , 02:57)

Even as a native speaker, I'm not sure I could pinpoint the exact difference. Maybe collecting some examples for the usage of "auszählen" in this sense can help to clear the picture. Of course, there's the usage in the context of votes, "Die Stimmen werden ausgezählt". And there's the usage in microbiology, "die Bakterienkolonien in der Petrischale auszählen". As a first thought, maybe the gist is that the result of the count has direct consequences? Like, who won the vote, does this sample count as "infected" etc.?

Auszählen means doing the statistics. You don't simply count the votes —8,156— but you account them to one or another candidate —A got 4,427, B got 3,123, C got 599, seven votes void—.

In boxing someone knocked down is "counted down" to zero ("wird ausgezählt).  "Auszählen" would literally point at "aus" = "out and done".
"Auszählen" stresses that there is some unknown but definite number to be found by counting (and may also imply that this is a sequential or tedious process). Vote counting implies that the votes are cast and one just has to count these correctly, not meddling with that fact.
In the case "Schafe zählen" (counting sheep for sleep) oder "Wolken zählen" (leisurely counting clouds in the sky) the outcome is a number but the precise measure is not relevant. If the newspapers say "die Polizei zählte dreihundert Demonstraten" it means there were roughly 300 people, not precise measure intended.
